# Are there any flying creatures with truesight?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, vision-and-light, flight

Are there any flying creatures in the official rulebooks that have truesight?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: I wanted a flying creature with truesight to be a random encounter for a downtime activity but I couldn't find anywhere to search for creatures with truesite. I had completly forgotten about DNDB though.

Comment: Some fantastic answers on my very low effort question, I couldnt really think of how to make the question more fully fledged and useful though.

Comment: Not every question needs to be universally applied, have an upvote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 32 creatures with truesight and fly speeds

There are 32 creatures with truesight and fly speeds across all officially published material, [according to D&D Beyond's monster listing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-senses=4&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-movement=4&sort=cr). Their monster listing has options to filter by a number of things, including special senses and types of movement speeds.

This includes:

- 9 creatures listed in the SRD (those that are also republished in the *Monster Manual* or other books are excluded from the following counts)
- the [avatar of death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/avatar-of-death) from the [*deck of many things*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/deck-of-many-things) (DMG, p. 164); the *deck of many things* is actually in the SRD, but for some reason D&D Beyond doesn't show the avatar of death's statblock as being in the SRD as well (although [it is](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=218))
- 6 creatures in the *Monster Manual*
- the [Storm Giant Quintessent](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/storm-giant-quintessent) (*Volo's Guide to Monsters*)
- 5 creatures in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*
- 6 creatures/statblocks in the *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica*
- [Tiamat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tiamat) (*Rise of Tiamat*)
- [Fraz-Urb’luu](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/fraz-urbluu) and [Orcus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/orcus) (*Out of the Abyss*)
- the [atropal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/atropal) (*Tomb of Annihilation*)

Comment: This is really useful, and importantly, highlights the use of the DnDB search functionality. I really must remember to remember about it and us it more. As you came to the same answer as everyone else, and were the quickest I have accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @GPPK: Glad to help! :)

Comment: I think there's a lot more now.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: I think it's up to 44 now, per DDB? (Though it's possible some are specific/named variants of existing statblocks.)

Comment: That sounds right, I didn’t actually count page 3 XD

Comment: I can update this answer for you tomorrow if you like.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Sure, go for it :)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there are 32 creatures in officially published sourcebooks.

| Name | Type | CR | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monodrone | Construct | 1/8 | Monster Manual |
| Quadrone | Construct | 1 | Monster Manual |
| Berbalang | Aberration | 2 | Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes |
| Couatl | Celestial | 4 | Monster Manual |
| Battleforce Angel | Celestial | 5 | Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica |
| Gynosphinx | Monstrosity | 11 | Monster Manual |
| Arcanaloth | Fiend | 12 | Monster Manual |
| Erinyes | Fiend | 12 | Monster Manual |
| Firemane Angel | Celestial | 12 | Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica |
| Atropal | Undead | 13 | Tomb of Annihilation |
| Nalfeshnee | Fiend | 13 | Monster Manual |
| Ultroloth | Fiend | 13 | Monster Manual |
| Deathpact Angel | Celestial | 14 | Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica |
| Planetar | Celestial | 16 | Monster Manual |
| Storm Giant Quntessent | Giant | 16 | Volo's Guide to Monsters |
| Androsphinx | Monstrosity | 17 | Monster Manual |
| Demilich | Undead | 18 | Monster Manual |
| Sibriex | Fiend | 18 | Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes |
| Balor | Fiend | 19 | Monster Manual |
| Pit Fiend | Fiend | 20 | Monster Manual |
| Acererak Demilich | Undead | 21 | Monster Manual |
| Hutijin | Fiend | 21 | Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes |
| Isperia | Monstrosity | 21 | Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica |
| Solar | Celestial | 21 | Monster Manual |
| Geryon | Fiend | 22 | Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes |
| Aurelia | Celestial | 23 | Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica |
| Empyrean | Celestial | 23 | Monster Manual |
| Fraz-Urb'luu | Fiend | 23 | Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes |
|  |  |  | Out of the Abyss |
| Rakdos | Fiend | 24 | Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica |
| Orcus | Fiend | 26 | Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes |
|  |  |  | Out of the Abyss |
| Tiamat | Fiend | 30 | The Rise of Tiamat |
| Avatar of Death | Undead | ?? | Dungeon Master's Guide |

Answer (score 9):

## Yes, there are official flying creatures with truesight

Using [this](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-senses=4&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-movement=4) D&DBeyond search criteria, there are 32 creatures with flight and truesight.

Just those available in the basic rules, there's the [Androsphinx](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/androsphinx), [Balor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/balor), [Couatl](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/couatl), [Erinyes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/erinyes), [Gynosphinx](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gynosphinx), [Nalfeshnee](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/nalfeshnee), [Pit Fiend](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pit-fiend), [Planetar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/planetar) and [Solar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/solar).

Answer (score 8):

There are [plenty](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-senses=4&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-movement=4) of flying monsters who have truesight.

The lowest CR is 0 [Avatar of Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/avatar-of-death), followed by 1/8 [Monodrone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/monodrone), 1 [Quadrone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quadrone), and 2 [Berbalang](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/berbalang).

The highest is CR 30 [Tiamat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/tiamat).

Answer (score 3):

### There are quite a few

D&D Beyond is a great resource for searches like this. I've linked [a search for creatures with fly speed and truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-senses=4&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-movement=4)